# Filter by Condition in a list using custom Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google, google-sheets-filter

I've googled this various different ways, but haven't found anything that has worked. I have a list that needs to be Private filtered by condition using a custom formula in google sheets.

In Sheet2 I have a list of names with shifts in Column C, in Sheet1 I have a list of shifts that correspond to a day of the week in Column B. I want the private filter to filter out by the list in Sheet1, Column B.

I have used `=Regexmatch(C:C,Sheet1!B:B)`, I have used `=Countif(C:C,Sheet1!B:B)`, I have used `=C:C=Sheet1!$B:$B` and nothing has worked please help. Thank you

Edited to add:
I have included a link to a sample sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s_M7U5QwdSF1hEJ_7tPP3_PmfS_OIL27JFbceTGRUzY/edit?usp=sharing
First tab has the shifts by day of the week, second tab has names with shifts. [image: Screenshot of the filter view by condition] If I create a new filter view and name it Tuesday, I would like the shifts from Tuesday to be automatically be filtered based on the custom formula that pulls from the list in the "Shifts" tab.

Comment: Hi and welcome. The terms that you have used in your question are unclear - specifically `a list of names with shifts` and `list of shifts that correspond to a day of the week`. Would you please edit your question to provide some sample data for Sheet1-Column N and Sheet2-Column C, and an example of how a successful outcome would appear.

Comment: @Tedinoz thank you for the feedback, I added a sample sheet and picture

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly... presently "Tuesday" shows a list of "Shift groups" (Team A, B, C &D). Your goal is to create a list of the names of the people working in those shift groups - that is, create a list of the names of people working on Tuesday. Is that right?

Comment: _I added a sample sheet and picture_ Your picture shows the `Filter` menu process. This is not important - what you need to do is show a picture of the **outcome** of a successful filter. You'll have to create this manually. Hint: don't worry trying to put the filter icons in the header row, just show the header and data that you would expect to see.

Comment: You've written this question with the expectation of using a filter. I wonder whether this is what is known as an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/399653); that is you've focused on a specific way of solving a problem, rather than describing the problem and being open minded about how it might be solved. For example, I think it likely that the outcome that you want using the method can't be done using the technique that you proscribed BUT it is possible to get that same outcome using other means. Would you access an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1):

You want to "filter" a list of names (with shift groups) based on shift groups.

**Option#1 - Filter (menu)**

`=arrayformula(ifna(match(C2:C22,Shifts!$B$2:$B$5,0),0))>0`

- `Filter` the "Shifts" column

  - select `Filter by Condition`
  - select `Custom formula`
  - enter the formula.

Using `match`, the formula returns the index value of a match between Shifts (Column C2:C22) and the values in the "Tuesday" column of the "Shifts" sheet (Shifts!$B$2:$B$5). If there is no match, the formula returns a value of zero. By making the condition  = `>0`, the formula will return only those matching values.

This formula has a disadvantage - the filtered day from the `Shifts` sheet is hard-coded which makes it inconvenient to change.

[image: filter]

---

**Option#2 - Query: hardcoded 'day'**

`=query(Names!A1:C22,"select C, A, B where "&"C='"&textjoin("' OR C = '",true,Shifts!B2:B5)&"' order by C",1)`

Enter this formula in any sheet, and it will return the same information as the `filter` option.

- Note, that filtered day from the `Shifts` sheet is hard-coded.

[image: query_hardcoded]

---

**Option#3-Query: Select Day from Dropdown**

`=query(Names!A1:C22,"select C, A, B where "&"C='"&textjoin("' OR C = '",true,indirect(address(2,match($H$1,Shifts!A1:G1,0),4,true,"Shifts")&":"&address(100,match($H$1,Shifts!A1:G1,0),4)))&"' order by C",1)`

- Enter the formula in any cell
- Create a Data Validation dropdown (cell H1) by referencing the range `=Shifts!$A$1:$G$1`.

The formula now references the "day" by matching the dropdown value. This approach makes it easy to modify data reporting.

[image: query_dropdown]